# Reloading Passenger gracefully when running Nginx + Passenger + RoR application?

Tags: nginx, passenger

When running a Ruby on Rails application with Nginx + Passenger combination, I'm getting the following error when I try to reload Nginx to update its configuration.

Both "nginx -s reload" and "kill -HUP NGINX_PID" results in the same error.

```
2019/09/04 15:00:32 [error] 5247#0: *53603 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 8.8.8.8, server: example.com, request: "GET /example/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/var/run/passenger-instreg/passenger.hDDqk0o/agents.s/core:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/example2"
```

This seems to happen when passenger is restarting. Although it logs the following message:

```
age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1216 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
```

It looks like it's not waiting and current requests are dropped, resulting in 502 errors.

This issue doesn't happen when I only restart the application with tmp/restart.txt. It only happens when I need to reload Nginx config.

Is there a way to reload Nginx configuration without dropping current Passenger requests?

I'm running Passenger 5.3.7 with Nginx 1.14.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I found was to run Passenger standalone and use Nginx as a proxy.

It required some configuration changes but now I can reload Nginx without dropping any requests or getting 502 errors.

What I did was:

1. Removed all passenger related config directives from Nginx configuration file
2. Started passenger standalone with: passenger start --port 4000 -a 127.0.0.1 --user myapp /home/myapp/path # ( you probably some custom directives here for your app )
3. Configured Nginx to proxy requests

Sample Nginx config:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

You will have to use --ssl and --ssl-port if you want Passenger standalone to also respond to SSL requests and you probably want to setup some type or monitoring/auto start for it but I guess it's outside the scope of this question.